# tinyMCE click outside, textarea hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, textarea

I have a tinyMCE textarea, in div named text_editor.
So i have in my jQuery:

```
$('#text_editor').hover(function(){ 
           mouse_is_inside=true; 
   }, function(){ 
           mouse_is_inside=false; 
   });

$('body').mouseup(function(){
    if(! mouse_is_inside){
            $('#text_editor').hide();

    }
});
```

with this when the user click outside the div text editor, this will hide, but if the user select a font family or a font size, the text editor hide, so i add this in my jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.mceMenuItem, .mceColorSplitMenu, .mceBottom, .mceMoreColors', function(e){
       e.stopPropagation(); 
       $('#text_editor').show();
    });
```

this resolve the problem overhead. but if the users click in the colorpicker-more colors, a new window open, and text_editor hide, and i don't want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *[demo](http://jsbin.com/ecawab/2/edit)*

```
var $editor = $('#text_editor');

$('textarea').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $editor.fadeTo(400,1);
});


$('body').on('click', function ( e ) {
  if( !($(e.target).is('#text_editor')) && $editor.is(':visible') ){
    $editor.hide();
  }
});
```